# Multiple methods in one string?

Tags: java, string, methods, line

I want to use two methods for one string somewhat like this

`outputLabel.setText(firstname.charAt(0) + toLowerCase());`

How can I get it to return the character at a certain position and also convert the string to lowercase?

I want the output to be a single character, converted to lower case, and on a single line.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Character.toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase%28char%29) followed by [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29):

```
outputLabel.setText(String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(firstname.charAt(0))));
```

Comment: @BinyaminSharet actually using `""+...` is less efficient than using `String.valueOf(...)`, but that's just picking.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - you're probably right, I meant from the given answers.

Comment: instead of `"" +`, use `Character.toString( )`. It might be a little more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Chain them like this:

```
outputLabel.setText(firstname.toLowerCase().charAt(0))
```

You cannot do it the other way around, because `.toLowerCase()` does not work on characters which is what `charAt()` returns.

Comment: Should the `charAt(0)` better be `substring(0, 1)`, to fit the `String` that the ´setText´ method expects?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`str.toLowerCase().charAt(0)`

This converts whole line to lower case and takes the first character.

Comment: And what if line VERY VERY long?

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter, since the label still has to fit on the screen.